aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError: 404, message='Not Found' aiogram
if message.photo:
    file_id_photo = message.photo[-1].file_id
    file_path = await bot.get_file(file_id_photo)
    await bot.download_file(file_path.file_path, f'media/{file_id_photo}.jpg')

aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError: 404, message='Not Found'

когда перешёл на локальный сервер telegram bot api, стала появляться данная ошибка, хотя на публичном всё хорошо работало. Спасибо за любую помощь
